# How to make a div on top of every other element of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a dropdown list with checkboxes from scratch since the project on which I am working on has to be supported by older version of IE. And the result is pretty good except for one part. when I click on the drop down list every other element of the page gets lowered down.

The behaviour that I'm trying to achieve is the same of an element select where it will go on top of any other element of the page. Is there a CSS property (or pure JS) that will let me do that.

Here is the code:

```js
var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');
var items = document.getElementById('items');
document.getElementById('anchor').onclick = function(evt) {
  if (items.className.indexOf("visible") !== -1) {
    items.className = "";
    items.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    items.className = " visible";
    items.style.display = "block";
  }


}
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
    <span id="anchor" class="anchor">Type</span>
    <ul id="items" class="items">
      <li><input type="checkbox" />Choice 3</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" />Choice 2</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" />Choice 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h1>
    this shou
  </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Answer updated : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49414138/1636522. I'm not seeking any reward, I just wanted to have fun. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` for the checklist...it will remove the element from the flow of document resulting does not affect on other elements...

Also use `position:relative` to the parent container `.dropdown-check-list`

```js
var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');
var items = document.getElementById('items');
document.getElementById('anchor').onclick = function(evt) {
  if (items.className.indexOf("visible") !== -1) {
    items.className = "";
    items.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    items.className = " visible";
    items.style.display = "block";
  }


}
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  top: 100%;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
    <span id="anchor" class="anchor">Type</span>
    <ul id="items" class="items">
      <li><input type="checkbox" />Choice 3</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" />Choice 2</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" />Choice 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h1>
    this shou
  </h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

My humble contribution :

```js
var addButton = document.getElementById("add");
addButton.onclick = addDropdown;
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  addDropdown.call(addButton);
}

document.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
  var el = ev.target;
  if (hasClass(el, "dropdown")) {
    let list = closestDropdownList(el);
    if (hasClass(el, "active")) {
      list.style.display = "none";
      removeClass(el, "active");
    } else {
      var t = el.offsetTop;
      var l = el.offsetLeft;
      var h = el.offsetHeight;
      list.style.left = l + "px";
      list.style.top = t + h + "px";
      list.style.display = "block";
      addClass(el, "active");
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener("blur", function (ev) {
  var el = ev.target;
  if (hasClass(el, "dropdown")) {
    let list = closestDropdownList(el);
    list.style.display = "none";
    removeClass(el, "active");
  }
}, true);

function addDropdown () {
  var els = [];
  var el = this;
  var parent = this.parentNode;
  while (!hasClass(el, "dropdown")) {
    el = el.previousSibling;
    els.push(el.cloneNode(true));
  }
  while (els.length > 0) {
    parent.insertBefore(els.pop(), this);
  }
}

function hasClass (el, name) {
  if (!el.getAttribute) {
    return false;
  } else {
    var attr = el.getAttribute("class");
    attr = " " + attr + " ";
    name = " " + name + " ";
    return attr.indexOf(name) >= 0;
  }
}

function removeClass (el, name) {
  var attr = el.getAttribute("class");
  attr = " " + attr + " ";
  name = " " + name + " ";
  attr = attr.replace(name, " ");
  attr = attr.slice(1, -1);
  el.setAttribute("class", attr);
}

function addClass (el, name) {
  var attr = el.getAttribute("class");
  attr += " " + name;
  el.setAttribute("class", attr);
}

function closestFollowing (el, predicate) {
  while ((el = el.nextSibling) && !predicate(el));
  return el;
}

function closestDropdownList (el) {
  return closestFollowing(el, function (sibling) {
    return hasClass(sibling, "dropdown-list");
  });
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
.dropdown:after {
  content: "";
  margin-left: .4em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
.dropdown-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  display: none;
  padding: .2em;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-list li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .25em;
}
.dropdown-list li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<button class="dropdown">Choose</button>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li>Option A</li>
  <li>Option B</li>
  <li>Option C</li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add dropdown</button>
<p>Hello World&nbsp;! Hello World&nbsp;! Hello World&nbsp;!</p>
```

Event delegation for "focus" and "blur" : [quirksmode.org](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html).

Answer (score 0):

For the div you can use z-index: 2
and the other elements z-index: 1

The highest value is in the front

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position: absolute` on `items` to achieve that:

```
.items {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```